# Am I understanding Excel references correctly?

Tags: excel, function

I'm trying to program my Excel document to help me calculate weekly costs of products I buy, on a shifting database. So far I made three sheets within the document.
Sheet1 has input data
Sheet2 processes Sheet1 data values
Sheet3 spits out a weekly income.

[image: Sheet1]

[image: Sheet2]

I am able to reference the cells ='Sheet1'!C2 in Sheet2.
What I want to do is reference a static column (i.e. Sheet1 insert new column 'C', making old 'C' to 'D') without breaking my function.

I've tried ='Sheet1'!$C3' but the moment I shift the column in Sheet1, Sheet2 does not keep the function 'Sheet1'!$C3.
Instead it translates to 'Sheet1'!$D3

Of course I can simply just fix my Sheet2 reference cell each time (changing from 'Sheet1'!D3 to !C3) with a new column in Sheet1 but if I don't have to keep fixing the function that would be fantastic.

How do I keep my reference cell from changing referenced column?

(I don't need to use $D$3 because I have a vertical line of cells I need to read.)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/51918 ?

Comment: Was about to answer with `INDIRECT`, but then read the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can reference the cell using R:C format so for `='Sheet1'!$C3` you can change it to `='Sheet1'!$3:3`. The idea is you use the `:` to separate the columns and the rows. you then convert the column portion to its corresponding number value such as A=1, B=2 C=3...

Comment: As an aside I see it as best practice to try to avoid adding columns to the left side of my data and instead add it to the right. If I am picky about the order of the columns what I do is have a hidden tab that actually hold the data i need where I add to the right every time and then use a different sheet where I bring over the things I need using Vlookups, Hlookup, or Index match depending on what is needed.